# Restart google chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In chrome, if I go to **chrome://flags/** and make a change on the flags page ( enable/disabe features ), a button appears at the bottom of the page which when clicked restarts chrome and re-opens the pages that were opened.
Does anyone know what javascript code allows that to happen ?

This is the html where the button appears

```
<div class="needs-restart" jsdisplay="needsRestart">
        <div i18n-content="flagsRestartNotice">NEEDS_RESTART</div>
        <button class="experiment-restart-button"
                type="button"
                i18n-content="flagsRestartButton">RESTART</button>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you building a plugin or is this JS on a webpage?

Comment: It is the JS on the webpage. chrome://flags opens a webpage ( I can view the source) but I cannot figure out what causes the browser to restart on the click of the button that is on the page. I do not see any code

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4551244/464257

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A restartBrowser() function is called from the click of that button.

From flags.js:

```
/**
 * Asks the C++ FlagsDOMHandler to restart the browser (restoring tabs).
 */
function restartBrowser() {
  chrome.send('restartBrowser');
}
```

Like the comment implies, it hooks into the C++ code behind Chrome, which will attempt a restart.

Comment: I just found this too. But do we know if either `restartBrowser()` or `chrome.send()` are available from anywhere besides `chrome://flags/`?

Comment: I just checked and found `restartBrowser()` is not available elsewhere. `chrome` is available elsewhere but in those cases it doesn't have a `.send()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript by itself does not allow you to restart the browser. If it did, websites could restart your browser whenever they wanted, which would be annoying for the user. The **chrome://flags/** has special permission to interact with the browser and tell it to request a restart. This code is not shown; it's part of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no javascript solution for that but you can type in the url bar : 
[chrome://restart](http://chrome://restart)

in order to restart google chrome manually.

If you try this trick using Javascript:

```
window.location = 'chrome://restart';
```

then you will get an error message that says "*Not allowed to load local resource:*"

Answer (score 0):

Entering the following into the address bar restarts Chrome:

```
> chrome:restart
```

But you'll need to find a way to call it:
http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html