# Clear all cookies in a userscript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How to clear all cookies or at least restart the browser in a tampermonkey/greasemonkey script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart google chrome using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792230/restart-google-chrome-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the cookies edit your Chrome shortcut (or write a shell script in Linux/MacOS) and add

```
 --remote-debugging-port=1234
```

(or use a random port number that's [not used by other processes](https://www.google.com/search?q=find%20unused%20local%20port%20number)) so you can send [`Network.clearBrowserCookies`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-clearBrowserCookies) RDP command:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Clear cookies
// @match       https://www.example.org/*
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @connect     localhost
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  url: 'http://localhost:1234/json',
  responseType: 'json',
  method: 'GET',
  onload(e) {
    const ws = new WebSocket(e.response[0].webSocketDebuggerUrl);
    ws.onopen = () => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({id: 1, method: 'Network.clearBrowserCookies'}));
    };
    ws.onerror = console.warn;
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @Kilrobot if you find this is the answer just click the "green check icon" on the left of this answer to accept this as a right answer.